Can I use a High Rated DC Power Connector
I was having issues with my guitar amp (Positive Grid Spark 40-Watt) so I decided to open it up and take a look.
I found the problem right away, which was the DC input Connector attached to the PCB had broken, one of the pins had snapped off, causing the amp to turn off and on.
I have looked for a replacement component, but I haven't found anything that matches the power supplies 19 V, 2.5 A specification. I have only found parts that are rated for 16 V, 5 A or 20 V, 5 A like a SPC21365.
I imagine that the higher amps aren't a problem since the amp should just draw what it needs, but I'm am worried about the high/lower rated voltage since I can't find a 19 V specific model (I am also having problems finding a suitable 20V part).
So would a 20 V, 5 A DC power connector work, and if so where can I find a suitable part?? Thank you very much for helping.


The rated voltages and currents are the maximums you are allowed to use.
Using a 20V 5A connector for 19V 2.5V is  perfectly fine.
Same goes for other things too. You can use a 16A mains plug or extension cord for a 1A load.

Thank you very much, I really appreciate that. didn't wasn't to throw away my amp over a part that costs a few Pounds.

Make sure you get the right size. Unfortunately, there are many different combinations of pin (inner) and sleeve (outer) diameter for what is generically called a "barrel" connector. Measure carefully, sometimes they differ by as little as 0.1 mm.

Yeah, I've been looking at the manufactures Specifications to make sure I get the right size.
